# Save a java object in a Access database and retrieve it again later

Tags: java, ms-access

I have a problem to store all bytes of array in my Access database.

```
    KeyPair pair = Certificate.generateKeyPair();        
    X509Certificate cert = Certificate.generateCertForCAroot(pair);       
    byte [] bytes = cert.getEncoded();

    X509Certificate cert2 = Utils.Certificate.recreateCertFromBytes(bytes); 
    byte [] bytes2 = cert2.getEncoded();

    if(cert2.equals(cert))System.out.println("0K**************:)");
    else System.err.println("KO000#########################:(");      

    AccessBD bd = new AccessBD("C:\\Users\\khaled\\Desktop\\BDtest.accdb","","");
    bd.connexion();
    Connection con = bd.getCon();  
    String sql ="insert into Client(nom,certificat)values(?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pstmt = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
    pstmt.setObject(1, "CAroot");
    pstmt.setObject(2, bytes);
    pstmt.execute();
    pstmt.close();        

    sql="select * from Client where nom='CAroot'";        
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
    rs.next();
    String s = rs.getString("nom");
    System.out.println(s);
    //rs.next();
    byte [] bytes3 = rs.getBytes("certificat");        
    ps.close();
    System.out.println("length bytes: "+bytes.length+"  length bytes2: "
            +bytes2.length+ " length bytes3: "+bytes3.length);

    bd.deconnexion();
```

Output:

```
0K**************:)
connexion a la base OK 
CAroot
length bytes: 498  length bytes2: 498 length bytes3: 249
deconnexion a la base OK 
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Comment: I have attempted to answer your question, although it's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: What is the data type of Certificate column in your Access DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's conspicuous that the data you're getting back is half the length you expect, suggesting a problem with character encoding. If I recall, Access string fields can be set to auto pack unicode data, so that might be involved.

Comment: How can I change the Type please ?

Comment: within access, open the table in design view, select the field, change the "Unicode compression" setting.  But that might not be the problem... could be the API either storing the data, or retrieving it. And if you really want to save bytes unmolested maybe use BYTE type field, though that wont be viewable in Access UI. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-data-types-HP001032248.aspx

Comment: In acces view when I select my field the size limite is 255 and I can not change it

Comment: See the link I posted: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/sql-data-types-HP001032248.aspx CHARACTER fields are limited to 255 characters. MEMO (TEXT aka MEMO) fields can be any length, but cannot be indexed.

Comment: But I also read on that page that TEXT and MEMO fields with compression enabled are compressed on save, and uncompressed when read, so that is not your issue, apparently. Still could be the API you are using though.

Comment: I have change the SGBD to MySQL

Comment: For the home viewers: "SGBD" = "DBMS"

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `PerparedStatement.setBinaryStream()` method per [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/467308/JDBC/databases/setBlob-method-fro-preparedstatement).  Also make sure your data type in Access is the equivalent of a `BLOB`

Comment: when i do this : `java.sql.Blob b2 = new SerialBlob(bytes);  
        pstmt.setObject(2, b2);` I have this error: java.sql.SQLException: SQL Exception : Unknown SQL Type for PreparedStatement.setObject (SQL Type=1111

Comment: `java.sql.Blob b2 = new SerialBlob(bytes);  
        pstmt.setBlob(2, b2);` 
Error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException